# Why am I seeing the SE network icons exchanged?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Basically, when visiting profile pages or looking at the HNQs the SE sites icons are exchanged for me. CV appears with SuperUser icon, while Personal Finance & Money (money.SE) appears with the Movies & TV (movies.SE) icon, for example. Not reproducible out of Stats.SE it seems.

---

Here's how it looks

[image: Recent inbox messages tab with wrong icons for Cross Validated]

Comment: I'm not seeing that right now. How long has this been going on? What browser, etc, are you using? What happens if you restart your browser or your machine?

Comment: @gung Hmm for an instant I thought it had gone after the browser restart, but nope. I noticed it today during work break and I'm using Firefox 48.0. Can't restart the PC right now. And now it happens outside CV too haha. But not all icons are affected.

Comment: @Andre I wonder if there's a word missing in your comment. Do you mean that it is happening to you also, or that it isn't happening to you either?

Comment: Relevant questions on meta.SE: [1. Same question; not answered yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283497/hot-network-questions-website-icons-scrambled) ...

[2. Possibly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283428/icons-of-meta-se-and-stack-apps-have-gone-missing)

Comment: Oh, and it's everywhere. When I click the recent inbox messages, I see the SuperUser icon for notifications here on CV.

Comment: @Glen_b I see Nick Craver mentioned there was some sort of test on the image path code today, in the second thread. That must be it then.

Answer (score 6):

Adam Lear commented on ["Hot Network Questions" website icons scrambled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283497/hot-network-questions-website-icons-scrambled) (thanks Glen_b for pointing this thread in the comments).

> We have a race condition where when we update the favicon sprite map
>   (which happened earlier today for a new private beta launch),
>   depending on which web server you're hitting, you could end up with
>   new cachebreakers and old images if you visit a site during a prod
>   build.
>
> I'll ask around tomorrow to see what, if anything, we can do about
>   that. AFAIK this didn't used to be a thing, **but it seems to be
>   happening pretty reliably to folks with every site we launch now**.

I think that's it then.

---

<s>As of now this is not particularly related to CV, I suppose we could close the question already?</s>

---

It's not happening anymore.

Comment: The underlying issue is still not fixed, just the symptom, at this time. We are working on our deployment process in order to resolve it for good, but that's still a ways away.